# Is it possible to type a convert function that takes the nested property and swaps it with the shallow property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to make a type for a generic `convertDeepToShallow` function.

Input: `{ a: { b: any } }`
Output: `{ b: { a: any } }`

but also

Input: `{ a: { b: any }, primitive: number }`
Output: `{ b: { a: any }, primitive: number }`

I've tried the following but this breaks apart when "combining" the two variants

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;

type ConvertType = <
  T extends Record<string, Primitive | Record<string, Primitive>>,
  TKey extends keyof T,
>(
  input: T,
) => {
  [A in keyof T[TKey]]: T[keyof T] extends Record<string, any>
    ? {
        [A in keyof T]: T[TKey][keyof T[TKey]];
      }
    : never;
} & {
  [A in keyof T]: T[A] extends Primitive ? T[A] : never;
};

const converter = (() => {}) as any as ConvertType;

const convObj = converter({ gap: { md: '' } }); // should be { md: { gap: string }}
//    ^?
const convPrimitive = converter({ primitive: 2 }); // should be { primitive: number }
//    ^?
const convBoth = converter({ gap: { md: '' }, primitive: 1 }); // should be { md: { gap: string }, primitive: number }
//    ^?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCBuAKH6hIUAMItCmOMAAq4bFAA8-KFBlQIAD2ARCAE1xQAShADGLOHsX4ixADSxEKNJiYnzl6wQQkH8ZKgYEAB8wXYqagDSECAa2roGUADWMSwAZmrhwQAUET5gVMAAXJn8AJRQWMFQAN4RANoAglA+yakZMvUy0SAAur0lnSkg6Wq9cTr6hu4WVjY+9lA8IMERqgD8tWuqO00thG0jHQNqXT299cOjnd0x-QI7OwC+2yWEEFICT1AAZFuqe1aV2Ogya4y0k0S-mcQSgm06jXGbw+DC+An45kI+CgmKkOkYOGy2QqVVqTwqXEMyyWhnEkgYsnk6Mx2NxAHlaAArSo4iR4hjZGpQYhcMAlIVIPQlADk0qg33JvCgAHplXgABYsKjsPTMaASqW1YWikrzEjyl6qx4APXWGIkrL50MCrhwuIZAqFYCcLogJQATPKykqrbhNdrdfQjd6Ai4-ZQaPRGJa1TtbfascBeZIAEIsYDqnnu6Se41io2SmVyp4OGMwzAlACMQZDarDWp1eorhqFIvLZtINagdd9b0TDHl-CtabtQA)

Comment: What about dupes? `{ a: { b: any }; c: { b: any } }`? Presumably `{ b: { a: any; c: any; } }`?

Comment: You can get the deeper keys first, map over those, then get the corresponding parent keys for each of them: https://tsplay.dev/w8XvPw

Answer (score 0):

Let's first get the nested keys:

```
type DeeperKeys<T, Values = Extract<T[keyof T], object>> = Values extends Values
    ? keyof Values
    : never;

type T = DeeperKeys<{ a: { b: any } }>;
//   ^? "b"
```

Then, mapping over these keys, we can extract the shallow keys whose values contain these deep keys:

```
type Convert<T> = {
    [K in DeeperKeys<T>]: {
        [P in keyof T as K extends keyof T[P] ? P : never]: K extends keyof T[P]
            ? T[P][K]
            : never;
    };
} & {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Primitive ? K : never]: T[K];
} extends infer O
    ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
    : never;
```

At the end, we add back the keys who have primitive values, and simplify the intersection. Here's an example input and output:

```
type T01 = Convert<{
    a: { b: string };
    c: { b: string; d: string };
    primitive: number;
}>;
/*
type T01 = {
  b: { a: string; c: string };
  d: { c: string };
  primitive: number;
}
*/
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCBuAKH6hIUACIQIkOAGkIIXAB4AKgBooANS7sqEXFBwBRAB4EuAY2DKA2gGs5LAGZQlAXTUtaAKwgWAfL-0NLR09CBMIQgATPU1tXX4oRKgAfig7EEcguNwEpIAuSghMOAEhcGglQPFJBll5BQBvKC4CptoCnhAoAF8e31LhaABhFkJiyyUAnAbcxKtpKARCMQkpOsVJl1bZpLmYReX0zMquPQWw4AjotPsnJSsYFxTYKALCIoYtqHPwqL0ju4PFw7Xa7VL3R7zYGgmGvQrFAS7boCXoAMigM128wONwyd2aenu0ieFyuengyFQGGgqQWbw+cC+RJcKKgpL+BwcDCgAHkdqkmtilrjMjyvjyoT0dvSEYIAPQAKn4mOYrWaBXwRGIvCgZg1BCWpGRuUiar1eANJB6iKgYEQKDQmDeNHoJX43X4CrlZRESgADABGQIjMYMSwqxItDGqi1a607c1tfVanWm2OG+O7O2Ux0QZ10Bgo-r8IA)